# Click to zoom a picture

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm using thumbnail from bootstrap and I want to make that when I click on that thumbnail to appear the picture with original sizes and when I click somewhere that picture with original sizes to disappear.
I hope you can understand me what I'm trying to explain..
This is an example of my thumbnail code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
```

Comment: I searched on google and I found only methods with javascript :) but I want to know if it's possible to make it without javascript

Comment: What's wrong with JavaScript? Without it, your best bet is `<a target="_blank">` to the URL of the full-size image to make it open in a new window.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ha! You cannot make it work without JavaScript.

Comment: Furthermore, you should not try and do this without JavaScript. This sort of manipulation is not what CSS is for.

Comment: Okay, but do you guys know a simple code for javascript and php? easy to implement? :) Thanks.

Comment: @Dimas, you are looking for something like a Lightbox plugin http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the [CSS:onfocus](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp).

```
a.thumbnail:focus > img.small {
        visibility: hidden;
}
a.thumbnail:focus > img.large{
        visibility: visible;
}
```

Html:

```
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" tabindex="0">
      <img class="small" src="..." alt="..."></img>
      <img class="large" src="..." alt="..."></img>
    </a>
```

Note that `tabindex="0"` is necessary here to make `<a>` focusable.

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is a modal plugin. Bootstrap has one, but it is not suitable for this kind of use.

You can find one implementation and examples of how to use it here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

This may be overkill for your solution, but there are many alternatives to it.